# C++ Can't get cin to read end line char from file redirection

Tags: c++, hex, newline, cin

This is my first time posting so bear with me.

I have a file that I need to read the header in via redirection and I'm using cin to capture the bytes and store them for later use.

The hexdump for the file is:

```
42 02 02 02 ff 0a 00 00  00 19 00 00 00 ff
```

What I have:

```
char magic, cs1, cs2, cs3, selector;
char temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4;
cin >> magic;
cin >> cs1;
cin >> cs2;
cin >> cs3;
cin >> selector; 
//   
cin >> temp1;
cin >> temp2;
cin >> temp3;
cin >> temp4;
```

The first 5 bytes represent magicNumber, channelSize, channelSize, channelSize, selectorBit.
The next 4 bytes are a width value separated into 4 bytes in LSB to MSB.

When I use cin on 0a which is 10 in hex (the value I want) it reads it as a newline character and thus skips it.

```
cout << temp1 << endl;
cout << temp2 << endl;
cout << temp3 << endl;
cout << temp4 << endl;
```

This will contain (in hex):

```
0
0
0
19
```

cin skips over 0a and grabs the next value. Is there a way to force it to read 0a?

If any more info is needed, let me know. Thanks

-- Kyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `cin`, which is an `istream` expects the data to be text.

If you are working with binary data then `istream::get` and `istream::read` are what you are looking for.

```
std::cin.get(temp1)
std::cin.get(temp2)
std::cin.get(temp3)
std::cin.get(temp4)
```

Retrieves four byte values from the input stream.

```
char buff[4];
std::cin.read(buff, 4);
```

Will read the block of data into an array of chars for you. You could use a plain integer 
if the endianness matches that of the data.

Comment: Ahh, I figured I would have to use something different but its nice to know why.

Is there a way to declare std::cin up above so I dont have to use 
    
    std::cin.get()

every time and instead can use

    cin.get()

Comment: You mean `istream`, not `iostream`.

Comment: @Kyle `std::cin.get()` and `cin.get()` are equivalent if you are using `using namespace std`. I left the namespace in for clarity only. @JamesKanze Yes i do, thanks. Edited now.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code.  The first is that you're using
`>>` to read binary data; `>>` is for reading formatted text data.  (In
particular, the first thing `>>` does is skip white space.)  The second
is that you're trying to read binary data from `cin`.  This is undefined
behavior, because `cin` is opened in text mode.  On systems where the
two are identical (Unix), it will work, but on others, you may encounter
various surprises.  (The exact data you show will probably work under
Windows as well, depending on the library implementation, but other
binary data will fail: 0x1A will generally cause an end of file, 0x0D
will disappear if followed by a 0x0A, etc.  And an implementation could
reasonably remove null bytes from a text stream.)